# How to implement multi-level generics in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, polymorphism

I am working on a simple activity execution framework where developers define an activity that can be executed from a workflow.

To ensure type safety and improve developer productivity (with type hints), I would like to leverage OOP and generics in Typescript.

I have following `abstract` `BaseActivity` class.

```
export abstract class BaseActivity<ActivityInput, ActivityOutput> {
  public abstract execute(input: ActivityInput): ActivityOutput
}
```

With this, developers can define an activity like this:

```
type AddNumbersInput = {
  num1: number
  num2: number
}

export class AddNumbers extends BaseActivity<AddNumbersInput, number> {
  execute(input: AddNumbersInput): number {
    return input.num1 + input.num2
  }
}
```

Now, I want to implement an `ActivityExecutor` that can preserve `ActivityInput` and `ActivityOutput`.

`ActivityExecutor` does quite a bit more work in the background in addition to calling `execute` of a perticular activity.

What I am struggling with is that the `ActivityInput` and `ActivityOutput` is `unknown` at design time. What are some patterns / strategies to overcome this challenge?

*Obviously, the following code doesn't work. But, hopefully it gives enough idea on what I am trying to achieve conceptually.*

```
export class ActivityExecutor<A extends BaseActivity<ActivityInput, ActivityOutput>> {
  execute(input: ActivityInput): ActivityOutput {
    return new A().execute(input)
  }
}

// Intention is to recieve the following type hints:
// input for `addNumbers.execute` needs to be `AddNumbersInput` and
// Output of `addNumbers.execute` is `number`
const addNumbers = new ActivityExecutor<AddNumbers>()
const result = addNumbers.execute({num1: 3, num2: 3})
```

Comment: Your `ActivityExecutor` class constructor needs to take a activity constructor and hold onto it, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV7Xvm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, that works. I checked the playground. It ensures type safety while giving proper type hints. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the `ActivityExecutor` class needs to have a reference to a class constructor for the activity it's going to use, otherwise there will be nothing at runtime for it to call `new` on.  So you could define it like this:

```
class ActivityExecutor<I, O> {
    constructor(public Activity: new () => BaseActivity<I, O>) { }
    execute(input: I): O {
        return new this.Activity().execute(input)
    }
}
```

where `ActivityExecutor` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the same input `I` and output `O` type arguments from `BaseActivity`.  The constructor takes an `Activity` argument whose type is a zero-argument [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) for a `BaseActivity<I, O>`.  The `public` modifier makes it [a parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), so that the parameter is copied into a class property of the same name.  It's essentially the same as

```
class ActivityExecutor<I, O> {
    Activity;
    constructor(Activity: new () => BaseActivity<I, O>) {
        this.Activity = Activity;
    }
    execute(input: I): O {
        return new this.Activity().execute(input)
    }
}
```

Anyway, the `execute()` method now has access to the needed `this.Activity` class constructor so it can be implemented.

Let's make sure it works:

```
const addNumbers = new ActivityExecutor(AddNumbers);
// const addNumbers: ActivityExecutor<AddNumbersInput, number>
const result = addNumbers.execute({ num1: 3, num2: 3 });
// const result: number
console.log(result) // 6
```

Looks good.  The compiler understands that `new ActivityExecutor(AddNumbers)` produces a value of type `ActivityExecutor<AddNumbersInput, number>`, and thus that the `execute()` method takes an `AddNumbersInput` argument and produces a `number` output.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgQXgEsA3QiATwB4BJAGgQHkA+BAbwFgAoBHhABwCuIZIVgJQkGPAQ4AHjlgCIOABSEAdoIgAuBNQCUuhlwC+Xc5wp8cCPABM7AOQEBbEDihhqmpQgC8bFy8COquAIy6oW4eQbxRAEyRru5QphYoaBj2TskeGHLK6nYY2GD4RKQUlNnO0Z7eWvRRKSwc3LxyCkqqGlq6Nbn1PhCGIYOB7cE8UDgQAlDqCL1KAHRRYQgA1EvDa67xsTxmnMfpqOi2FWTkAKLyihAA9lA09MwTwQQQJNcA3IdIR7qSQCeDPFRfH4USI4ADuCBU+n8LFK5W+lSodEYTCRbSmvAgAAtCGAVpCMf5Lui-gDjsFOg8esNdAYjB98QgZnMFiE4QgiSSyVcKIiVgzumphvpaWlOFxYEDIOIHLUUhgAuo+eTrncuk8oBCVYMwPp-pwAPTmwHAxDAI11MD9YW3e5KZ7Ve1qhpKJqDJjyxWIGZgATIRABO05B1i13KFSsMYuCIIADMvpciVTCBMpq4lutSuDoZ0iZSAeBj2QOBWyEeAHMVEWw0j8wA2LhAA)